# How to release CODENAMEONE form including all it's components while navigating one page to other?

Tags: java, ios, codenameone

I have tried to release Form memory just to make that form null while navigate from one to other.

But null is not the solution of memory. memory increasing while navigate from one to other.

For ex: I have one heavy form and from which i navigate to the light form then memory occupied by heavy form should be released before showing light form and after that it should occupy memory of light form only.

This is the sample code which i have been used.

```
public class Form1 extends Form {
    Form main;
    public static void includeForm1(final Form form) {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.showForm1(form);

    }

    public void showForm1(Form form){
        form = null;
        this.main = new Form();
        ...
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainContainer);
        ....
        //Navigate to Form2
        Form2.includeForm2(main);
        ...
        this.show();
    }

}

public class Form2 extends Form {
    Form main;
    public static void includeForm2(final Form form) {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.showForm2(form);
    }

    public void showForm2(Form form){
        form = null;
        this.main = new Form();
        ...
        addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainContainer);
        ....
        //Navigate to Form1
        Form2.includeForm1(main);
        ...
        this.show();
    }


}
```

What change i need to perform to solve memory issue?

Answer (score 0):

If memory is increasing it's because you kept a reference to something. Even a reference to one component within the hierarchy will keep the entire form in RAM so just one button stored in the global scope can trigger that.